# I want to change DataFrame's value from str into int

Tags: python, pandas

I want to change DataFrame's value from str into int.
I wrote codes,

```
import scipy as sp
import scipy.stats
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
x = sp.stats.chi2_contingency(df)
print(x)
```

df variable has DataFrame table like

```
A B C D
0 23 45 18 49
```

When I run this codes,Traceback says

```
   x = sp.stats.chi2_contingency(df)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/stats/contingency.py", line 242, in chi2_contingency
    if np.any(observed < 0):
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

So I wrote codes

```
x = sp.stats.chi2_contingency(int(df))
```

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'DataFrame' error happens.What is wrong in my codes?How should I fix this?

Comment: `df.astype(int)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems values are strings, so convert them to numeric:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: '23'}, 'B': {0: '45'}, 'C': {0: '18'}, 'D': {0: '49'}})
print (df)
    A   B   C   D
0  23  45  18  49

x = sp.stats.chi2_contingency(df.astype(int))
print(x)
(0.0, 1.0, 0, array([[ 23.,  45.,  18.,  49.]]))
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.When I run your codes,ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'A' error happens.I think column name's A・B・C・D cannot convert into int type.How should I fix this?

Comment: What is `print (df.info())` ?

Comment: When I run the codes,
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1 entries, 0 to 0
Data columns (total 10 columns):
A       1 non-null object
B      1 non-null object
C       1 non-null object
D      1 non-null object
dtypes: object(10)
memory usage: 160.0+ bytes
None  is shown.

Comment: @user9619086 - So it means there are numeric and non numeric columns? What is `print (df.to_dict())` ?

Comment: It shows `{‘A’: {0: ’23'}, ‘B’: {0: ’45’}, ‘C’: {0: '18’}, ‘D’: {0: '49’}}`

Comment: I think there are numeric and non numeric columns.

Comment: with your sample data if failed?

Comment: Your df's type is <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>,right?

Comment: Sure. Try test it. There has to be something wrong, if my answer doesnt work for you.